# How to sort a list of Strings including integers in Python

Tags: python, sorting

Here is my input:

```
a = ['Dr1', 'Dr10', 'Dr11', 'Dr12','Dr2', 'Dr3']
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Here is the current output:

```
['Dr1', 'Dr10', 'Dr11', 'Dr12', 'Dr2', 'Dr3']
```

Here is the output I would like generated instead:

```
['Dr1', 'Dr2', 'Dr3', 'Dr10', 'Dr11', 'Dr12']
```

Comment: Are your strings always of the form `Dr` followed by a number? If so, you can just sort by `key=lambda x: int(x[2:])`, or the other things shown in the answers to the linked duplicate. But if the letters can be different, and you want to consider them—so, e.g., `Dr2` comes before `Dr10`, but `Mr1` comes after `Dr2`, you probably want a "natural sort" library rather than building it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort via the trailing value in each element, use `re`:

```
import re
a = ['Dr1', 'Dr10', 'Dr11', 'Dr12','Dr2', 'Dr3']
new_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:int(re.findall('\d+', x)[0]))
```

Output:

```
['Dr1', 'Dr2', 'Dr3', 'Dr10', 'Dr11', 'Dr12']
```